# Путь JSON в виде строки обратно в объект

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот есть такая задачка, нужно передать в функцию путь JSON в виде строки, например:

```
var json_str = "JSON.prop1.prop2.value";
```

и в итоге мне надо вернуть его обратно в нормальный вид. Можно конечно распарсить регулярками и собрать его, но может есть какой то другой метод, eval не предлагать, у меня 'use strict'.
Основная задача , есть ф-ция которая но вход получает JSON в виде строки, а вернуть она должна значение "value", или "false" в случае если "value" нету

Comment: что Вы уже сделали для решения данного вопроса? посмотрите в сторону `String#split()` и `Array#reduce()`

Comment: `eval` работает нормально с `use strict`. Хотя это и не влияет на то, что он тут не к месту.

Comment: @Qwertiy очень даже к месту , достаточно сделать eval("JSON.prop1.prop2.value") и с помощью catc'а отловить ошибку есть какого-то пропа нету

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: @Grundy описал проблему более развёрнуто

Comment: @vnn198, все еще плохо, добавьте пример json. если имеется ввиду строка которая уже в вопросе - то это не JSON. Добавьте простейший пример с входными и выходными данными

Comment: если действительно получаете JSON, то вам нужен `JSON.parse`

Comment: это не сам JSON ,а просто путь к нему, нужно либо получить проп если он есть, либо кинуть false , если его нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38230/discussion-between-vnn198-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = { prop1: { prop2: { value: 14 } } };
var keys = "JSON.prop1.prop2.value";
var value = obj;
for (var key of keys.split(".").slice(1)) value = value[key];
console.log(value);
```

Comment: да вот загвозкда в том что нельзя братьvar value = obj;

Comment: @vnn198, почему нельзя? дополните свой вопрос _всеми необходимыми_ данными

Comment: ну вот такова задача ;) , если есть внешний объект то всё достаточно просто, в этом у меня и возникла загвоздка, что без объекта не идёт каменный цветок, чувствую что всё идёт к eval'у

Comment: @vnn198, без объекта и `eval` не поможет. Если вы имеете ввиду что объект глобальный - то используйте `window` как начальный объект

Comment: вот в этом то и загвоздка, у меня node, и объект не обязательно глобальный